# Inster a post into a subcategory on the nav with WordPress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress Template using HTML 5 Blank but my client want to insert into the nav a subcategory

something like this

[image]

But i don't know how can I make it, i create a page of intenacionals and nationals and in my functions file i add this

```
// Create 1 Custom Post type for a Demo, called HTML5-Blank
function nacionales_post_type()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
    register_post_type('nacionales', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Nacionales', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'new_item' => __('New Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'view' => __('View Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'view_item' => __('View Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found' => __('No se encontraron Nacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No se encontraron Nacionales en la papelera', 'html5blank')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array(
        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));
}

// Create 1 Custom Post type for a Demo, called HTML5-Blank
function internacionales_post_type()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
    register_post_type('internacionales', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Internacionales', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'new_item' => __('New Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'view' => __('View Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'view_item' => __('View Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found' => __('No se encontraron Internacionales', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No se encontraron Internacionales en la papelera', 'html5blank')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category'
        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));
}
```

So i whant to know what do i need to add to the function to make that the post belong to the tour national or international

at the moment the nav looks like this

[image]

Comment: Use the menu builder, under Appearances... That's what i do, then I drag them a bit to the right.

Comment: But that is when I have other pages, that's not the situation, i whant that when i create a post, i add into the subcategory,i don't know if i xplain me

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mmm wow thanks you!!